# Reverse Engineer HTTP request

Tags: reverse-engineering, nsurlrequest

I intercepted an HTTP request on Charles originating from iPhone to Instagram and here are the headers

```
POST /logging_client_events HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.instagram.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Instagram 10.0.1 (iPhone8,1; iOS 10_1_1; en_IN; en-IN; en; scale=2.00; 750x1334) AppleWebKit/420+
Accept-Language: en-IN;q=1.0, hi-IN;q=0.9,
Content-Length: 1601
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

There is a Post data as well in the request that is compressed. My question is how can I uncompress the Post data? Perhaps any method in NSData that can decompress?

EDIT: Here is the complete HTTP request

```
POST /logging_client_events HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.instagram.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Instagram 10.3.0 (iPhone8,1; iOS 10_1_1; en_IN; en-IN; scale=2.00; gamut=normal; 750x1334) AppleWebKit/420+
Accept-Language: en-IN;q=1, hi-IN;q=0.9
Content-Length: 4585
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

message=eNrtXG1v4kgS%2FiunfLqTAupXtzvSfiAxZInOZsmQEPt0sowxYGNj1jZDYLX326%2FaMBNICJMsZCajTUZRwO6XqvJT1c%2FTtuePE286dcP%2BydkJJgwRxgUjumCYnZyezMrjCD4VYRKcnGGmU0GIQKiKGEWUnZa9PweZ6o6qtIr%2B8U%2BmIYGEwP%2BCbv3gc%2BgH6%2BHPBdcb51rFuJCNCmsYuKJf6EZFq%2BlMN2pGDV0I6DLwkjBeuJs9Gb1gBqnXK3rDqFfAPKMi8UWtYvCaIKyGOZM16JkHeR6mk1Wf8xqqo4sGhuYNvcIouaicn2ukQhr8HLzQ5LlGlYFe4Z2c%2FeePkyTtz2JwUTkExyee8vdkHvTy1B8Hheunk0ngF65XFEEyLR6HRJOkyhETQp6eBPdFBoP%2BcTIdwxCE6IxSHWvs5M8%2FT5%2BbKBy6vwducD9N81kW7Bxdl4xvDD7M0tkUehZBXrhgZOjFysgCGrgQBD8Og4kys4zGhhGnT8xSg06DDCaEDqUpYZq7gyDou7NB6GZBP8jD4eRg8zmjz9h%2FgJm59zk40DJJBZI7LMvSOE5nhxq3CmSRpnERTh9ZujoFneJwEjzYnAVB7IIxCzdMptkK1bss1zHBSGxYXvYBT8NC9ThDu%2ByMQ7CpnMFPZ8pYaFX220of1vOQlJT3PU2ygAVSoCDQexj7cuB5PoGBklkB1j8ayXOfzjjycjdZlC3LNp%2FDYP605ySYPz4U5u6Xo%2BD3kUMnNKy%2Fy9BxRDgl6L0GjhCKtPcYOCw1LHWpi3cbOU0I%2Bh4jxwXXpIDL%2Bl4jR%2BHL%2B0xWiTSJEf3ekQsneeENMy9x02zoTULfzWe9b0WRYUQ2gpinswwYVjpwPX8VxyezJS5YiNXf8P6ZMH9JPqYLKAyA8cdE7KG1SwhCmoHrFUSpVmE65hXJiKzUmDwX9QuBGoZWzroekmANuCb0pPCLMMLu1jTghz8OJ0NYXMeBMj9YXC29bn9m311jP7kJW2Ez%2FPfF1dy%2Bi%2FMeaYyb0VQ0k3h5Rxozu3vP%2B5dx5GOJ%2FKQReeRWnUf%2B5DaGPkvn7orA76B%2FKTOny9RY95YxXFrLOrIMe2EZTTIw6siM6sSM%2FLnZsZG5rBPLqN2bRkM3oyazDHPZMuDYr3NiR7W5Y9jEurSxZViRc2mFrc7VuHXZntvLm3tzeTuyl6NRq9tcOJGN7ChO7ATmjBqh1akRK7LnLaMxhvMwvjW2E5s1w3nYv7udOhdNrRn53InaBNou7K4zbnXgcxfGTG4jJ2kvra6JreUNjNskZqe9AHsX1rIG47eXpe1GfW5%2BupLgu%2FIb4ihnzSjFg%2FYvvyhWrrjQ3AXUFbNcIaX8DsE%2FjHsBJoXcxQo79U%2BdQ8nr57AfpK4fxLHrzYp0GkPy92bDAWB52%2BiV1niwe831FYT9kTcZ7jZdSkz2sf3TjXGUlAgH4dYxlbLFYqomvOhce%2F0wrfk%2BZE4n8EeTNE6Hi18%2FGb%2FVngY4Dn2vWCX52uDYm038kTvLvV6801hJgVNsqoe1yxCw30bpJNBPMXRL85WMw1X1LZyEBaSWux48gZOYy6rATEisqbKn3H%2Fq9Zd%2BE8BL2QlxGFAirlP40TQQjT1IXHWlJ31XtT45G3hxHjx0VQUJqrfqrWFRFZqmC45AnGJNf2i1crdspUtcZYKXhjGuYfqCoE1n%2BQiMLOC6rE7BylAUCtK7AsigdG1Wz57XHwYwc5HNwHAvDrLi67dcefb1246aCZpZZdKuS1eO605mSU%2BJaii5sQf67snRzJt%2FNfdM7MnBfpgp2ToLXciSwU7XBCZiExuDMIMppx7gfu0CrCqzWKVXPishujMP1XpXLk299F7Ns4J2Fvw%2BUwq1nBaOpgXo1P4sW12MM03yPcZngRerjipVcj8Le8E%2B%2FS2FBgDbcORrd0j%2B0IfxZnmQVfo5qTwY%2Fj%2By05nHM09LgHgxHO8voKSFubrcJWz32F%2Fq8UnhxqnXD%2Fo7bdYZQZs2f%2BmyDt90lBbpTgs3x15F9wwyF2LAOWFSSp0gjT40g5WiGAFUONpj78N2Rz%2Fsu%2Bk02EEkaFVyjW9JgFfsczy9ojvCwqqUUV2KvcX1hRf3lUQ0CwYA9tEumxgVQtP32nQ0zjkHLrnOtcEs%2FpKGO5noptlfUDMJinmajU9eSkLl42HWcGJaWRtQ%2BaMh%2FojkHpPlQ3w5FpQ8z%2FLpj1OWXFAJRIXoj2k%2BfkWED6L5iRdOVqxmD0Kh%2FGl4u%2F7lJffw07ivVpysgDEKf7SzoKy4HRjcV1MDVd%2BXx%2BWmsbIujstKnu%2ByR6dsfw4PehvjQCUocf4XBdA%2BcPEqSDQh5VupH5iDalIyio6qfiB%2BkhMuIAmRjqi7Nc0u9bPF3JWK%2BaYamlixP3FiP5aoR4q4FyolUUctw6SgYEirY3Jr6egrxQDqxxhjM7qhoIIWpjGcm3S%2BMKMhKB%2BTKRUBimhhdYb3ZtSmLaOf2F2lgGrcItdjk0CbaBRb3Zt767IRgWpatDo3S%2BvyOjSN25G1HHOrcwuqyEdWtxFZl%2FW51QFldGkqu6eg1Ea9pJEHd9dTm1qD%2Fq9XIxtsVuoHPmPn04YaSurUvFRKChTU0kocpXK61siM%2Bgkoqhj%2BhjAfKn14zrfFlXyl%2BnkxWFdL4HS1Q78LrJJpfw2sL1PoquNq%2BjMCpIEzqm5eYCY1rn8I8J9ZgL9qw2i9dn2zdEqdvg6Nz1v7gNRduHwp8p6i%2FAOL3wuLB%2BgdXuVcl1sc5TC9owuNcK2U%2FRTUn%2FZKvfMCewWMLI9mL0NIMkkFCDRo9gJ5dhT6o1Up4tv3OF9Nf%2FYtLQQxSoSG9OOyH0AKXF%2FEKcKYcndzlh9BflirYzNraQMpMSHD60vr7jH5sbnTGUJmQmYvx3Oze4PtTj80gciYBLK0cx1bSXthL60I%2Fo1tYlKr40Sm0ZxDJcGQ%2FcRW5KdTh6rgjFQGty6b34P8PPXt06vJzwj0fKr2WhfJYP30gNrb29CBfpokwaSvzoBW%2FxZkCSF4r3pYPZ1CYIXgjAssHvagnjVl656RFw%2FTLCxGyVengix3H46%2BsXtQucgL%2FKOQBpQTTfBX%2BYd%2FuH8gsrWXXD8oA1AWQem8yj%2By7Z%2FarXQzbzJ%2B1r9XFX6tyiRQDXG0wg%2FsWpdclBtzmKoHpx5XfinfQEuIKpFcZ%2FhnEL5bmoRwXRMCwbKlCZ2QD1n8t5DFL9AjCtEaouJjK%2BcDs%2B8Cs%2FvByghUsoPASvaBdePxk%2BNhVehch%2FVYEPiCBIywMcsPgKrPAIZzuKRwTknsGgUJ%2FQiqFpDoxtjstplFmthOGqHT8e%2FtTmNkR6OxgoDVuQZJPeROtxG2jPHcAahanThRnxUdb3Vux3b3BjnGVWR2AeCdm%2B8A1R2%2BXfyYXUcB0lwAzfwJNOIGUcBVrHON6QgopA5Vln0oyJ9YQR6XJ3C12vKPPY8PxL4dYl8lKgGSsLSS4%2B0mIoAGI7S8QY8Zpk%2F3EzVMDng%2BT1fPkyB%2B%2FJc2wAd1KzyfppM8zSAFY68XxErkfw6y%2FKD3OfQqIUKQNzB6%2FThhmqkHqsrHC4P5NM3UNRkOD4SGXqVUbD1fduh2g0YkxuWDQAA89VbSqzbGvx1lxgEZ2ptAI1x7nrqjcDiK4bd4DhpHoT56lYNZVPsJWPoG9UFV9QCqDiuE2uAB1v7B4f8OHH4f59GrwBw0chDnYXs5j65qKxXiyKRHI5rOOdQqwojmbk3zHcHa%2F8p6LHXMuMGtzpibUXthTR6D9Ta0uzazI8VynLGdXIV2p4nUPgiwHdS6tACw1xGwHYBQY%2BR04XPHiR3DX9qJAqpJHWNIACwwd3PRMtrcSerfBKsDx31ykzcnt9jrtsHXq5G1PA%2FNxFZAXDqJuu%2FcgLma1Insewf%2B2pHPLaPGzNX9adZS96ujIbbAt1Zpsx0O7tCbsR5ZRYKgIy5t6gU5QAyQHqxID%2FtON1FlVTABMx%2BSXPzHJBfGnHDJOOLsfSTXPVTmBQAQaH8NP1kJLq9CVelNVdWXQ%2BokbSUxVHIxc9kGMI8XZqKSq87MLlT6y%2Fa93W1je3kFssOcW0lz6VzeLCDhIAmdEFYPkBW175ZcICXU5iMcv4EVq%2F3GyaVrkqMjSgoGDeQ6u7g4ZnI9T8HK%2F0%2BASibJz7BybXMwiBaVYLxAAutU%2F1jYfuaF7Rksqzdn1OszvsqDMqFyN1N3wrOnObnGsvjWywvr3usnnv97egIq8kvOrv7vBjf4vMqVPPgdoPbn%2FwGSB1Nz&compressed=1&access_token=124024574287414%7C84a456d620314b6e92a16d8ff1c792dc&format=json
```

Comment: I'm trying to reverse engineer instagram view count increase mechanism. I captured queries with fiddler but I'm stuck here. Did you get any luck for instagram views?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*TL;DR:* use the following command line to decode such `message`s:

```
ipython -c "import zlib, base64, urllib; m='<message>';zlib.decompress(base64.decodestring(urllib.unquote(m)))"
```

While replacing `<message>` with the post parameter.

*Full details:*

This request uses several encoders one on top of another, but all encoders used are easily recognisable by an experienced researcher and probably experienced web developer.

By the characters appearing in the message POST argument, it's easy to identify the format is [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). However, percent characters (`%`) stand out as they're not part of the base64 character set. After further review it is easy to see a percent sign is always followed by only a few selection of characters (`%2B`, `%2F`). These are url encoded characters (specifically '+' and '/', respectively), both part of the base64 character set.

Thus, that string should be urldecoded and then base64 decoded, and we end up getting a more cryptic string as a result, but luckily no errors:

```
x\xda\xed\\mo\xe2H\x12\xfe+\xa7|\xba\x93\x02\xeaW\xb7;\xd2~
<snip>
```

The string consists of both printable and non-printable characters, but the first two characters, `x\xda` (or `\x78\xda`) have an important meaning as they're markers for a [zlib compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) stream.

For example, running that one-line with your message would look exactly like that:

```
nir$ ipython -c "import zlib, base64, urllib; m='eNrtXG1v4kgS%2FiunfLqTAupXtzvSfiAxZInOZsmQEPt0sowxYGNj1jZDYLX326%2FaMBNICJMsZCajTUZRwO6XqvJT1c%2FTtuePE286dcP%2BydkJJgwRxgUjumCYnZyezMrjCD4VYRKcnGGmU0GIQKiKGEWUnZa9PweZ6o6qtIr%2B8U%2BmIYGEwP%2BCbv3gc%2BgH6%2BHPBdcb51rFuJCNCmsYuKJf6EZFq%2BlMN2pGDV0I6DLwkjBeuJs9Gb1gBqnXK3rDqFfAPKMi8UWtYvCaIKyGOZM16JkHeR6mk1Wf8xqqo4sGhuYNvcIouaicn2ukQhr8HLzQ5LlGlYFe4Z2c%2FeePkyTtz2JwUTkExyee8vdkHvTy1B8Hheunk0ngF65XFEEyLR6HRJOkyhETQp6eBPdFBoP%2BcTIdwxCE6IxSHWvs5M8%2FT5%2BbKBy6vwducD9N81kW7Bxdl4xvDD7M0tkUehZBXrhgZOjFysgCGrgQBD8Og4kys4zGhhGnT8xSg06DDCaEDqUpYZq7gyDou7NB6GZBP8jD4eRg8zmjz9h%2FgJm59zk40DJJBZI7LMvSOE5nhxq3CmSRpnERTh9ZujoFneJwEjzYnAVB7IIxCzdMptkK1bss1zHBSGxYXvYBT8NC9ThDu%2ByMQ7CpnMFPZ8pYaFX220of1vOQlJT3PU2ygAVSoCDQexj7cuB5PoGBklkB1j8ayXOfzjjycjdZlC3LNp%2FDYP605ySYPz4U5u6Xo%2BD3kUMnNKy%2Fy9BxRDgl6L0GjhCKtPcYOCw1LHWpi3cbOU0I%2Bh4jxwXXpIDL%2Bl4jR%2BHL%2B0xWiTSJEf3ekQsneeENMy9x02zoTULfzWe9b0WRYUQ2gpinswwYVjpwPX8VxyezJS5YiNXf8P6ZMH9JPqYLKAyA8cdE7KG1SwhCmoHrFUSpVmE65hXJiKzUmDwX9QuBGoZWzroekmANuCb0pPCLMMLu1jTghz8OJ0NYXMeBMj9YXC29bn9m311jP7kJW2Ez%2FPfF1dy%2Bi%2FMeaYyb0VQ0k3h5Rxozu3vP%2B5dx5GOJ%2FKQReeRWnUf%2B5DaGPkvn7orA76B%2FKTOny9RY95YxXFrLOrIMe2EZTTIw6siM6sSM%2FLnZsZG5rBPLqN2bRkM3oyazDHPZMuDYr3NiR7W5Y9jEurSxZViRc2mFrc7VuHXZntvLm3tzeTuyl6NRq9tcOJGN7ChO7ATmjBqh1akRK7LnLaMxhvMwvjW2E5s1w3nYv7udOhdNrRn53InaBNou7K4zbnXgcxfGTG4jJ2kvra6JreUNjNskZqe9AHsX1rIG47eXpe1GfW5%2BupLgu%2FIb4ihnzSjFg%2FYvvyhWrrjQ3AXUFbNcIaX8DsE%2FjHsBJoXcxQo79U%2BdQ8nr57AfpK4fxLHrzYp0GkPy92bDAWB52%2BiV1niwe831FYT9kTcZ7jZdSkz2sf3TjXGUlAgH4dYxlbLFYqomvOhce%2F0wrfk%2BZE4n8EeTNE6Hi18%2FGb%2FVngY4Dn2vWCX52uDYm038kTvLvV6801hJgVNsqoe1yxCw30bpJNBPMXRL85WMw1X1LZyEBaSWux48gZOYy6rATEisqbKn3H%2Fq9Zd%2BE8BL2QlxGFAirlP40TQQjT1IXHWlJ31XtT45G3hxHjx0VQUJqrfqrWFRFZqmC45AnGJNf2i1crdspUtcZYKXhjGuYfqCoE1n%2BQiMLOC6rE7BylAUCtK7AsigdG1Wz57XHwYwc5HNwHAvDrLi67dcefb1246aCZpZZdKuS1eO605mSU%2BJaii5sQf67snRzJt%2FNfdM7MnBfpgp2ToLXciSwU7XBCZiExuDMIMppx7gfu0CrCqzWKVXPishujMP1XpXLk299F7Ns4J2Fvw%2BUwq1nBaOpgXo1P4sW12MM03yPcZngRerjipVcj8Le8E%2B%2FS2FBgDbcORrd0j%2B0IfxZnmQVfo5qTwY%2Fj%2By05nHM09LgHgxHO8voKSFubrcJWz32F%2Fq8UnhxqnXD%2Fo7bdYZQZs2f%2BmyDt90lBbpTgs3x15F9wwyF2LAOWFSSp0gjT40g5WiGAFUONpj78N2Rz%2Fsu%2Bk02EEkaFVyjW9JgFfsczy9ojvCwqqUUV2KvcX1hRf3lUQ0CwYA9tEumxgVQtP32nQ0zjkHLrnOtcEs%2FpKGO5noptlfUDMJinmajU9eSkLl42HWcGJaWRtQ%2BaMh%2FojkHpPlQ3w5FpQ8z%2FLpj1OWXFAJRIXoj2k%2BfkWED6L5iRdOVqxmD0Kh%2FGl4u%2F7lJffw07ivVpysgDEKf7SzoKy4HRjcV1MDVd%2BXx%2BWmsbIujstKnu%2ByR6dsfw4PehvjQCUocf4XBdA%2BcPEqSDQh5VupH5iDalIyio6qfiB%2BkhMuIAmRjqi7Nc0u9bPF3JWK%2BaYamlixP3FiP5aoR4q4FyolUUctw6SgYEirY3Jr6egrxQDqxxhjM7qhoIIWpjGcm3S%2BMKMhKB%2BTKRUBimhhdYb3ZtSmLaOf2F2lgGrcItdjk0CbaBRb3Zt767IRgWpatDo3S%2BvyOjSN25G1HHOrcwuqyEdWtxFZl%2FW51QFldGkqu6eg1Ea9pJEHd9dTm1qD%2Fq9XIxtsVuoHPmPn04YaSurUvFRKChTU0kocpXK61siM%2Bgkoqhj%2BhjAfKn14zrfFlXyl%2BnkxWFdL4HS1Q78LrJJpfw2sL1PoquNq%2BjMCpIEzqm5eYCY1rn8I8J9ZgL9qw2i9dn2zdEqdvg6Nz1v7gNRduHwp8p6i%2FAOL3wuLB%2BgdXuVcl1sc5TC9owuNcK2U%2FRTUn%2FZKvfMCewWMLI9mL0NIMkkFCDRo9gJ5dhT6o1Up4tv3OF9Nf%2FYtLQQxSoSG9OOyH0AKXF%2FEKcKYcndzlh9BflirYzNraQMpMSHD60vr7jH5sbnTGUJmQmYvx3Oze4PtTj80gciYBLK0cx1bSXthL60I%2Fo1tYlKr40Sm0ZxDJcGQ%2FcRW5KdTh6rgjFQGty6b34P8PPXt06vJzwj0fKr2WhfJYP30gNrb29CBfpokwaSvzoBW%2FxZkCSF4r3pYPZ1CYIXgjAssHvagnjVl656RFw%2FTLCxGyVengix3H46%2BsXtQucgL%2FKOQBpQTTfBX%2BYd%2FuH8gsrWXXD8oA1AWQem8yj%2By7Z%2FarXQzbzJ%2B1r9XFX6tyiRQDXG0wg%2FsWpdclBtzmKoHpx5XfinfQEuIKpFcZ%2FhnEL5bmoRwXRMCwbKlCZ2QD1n8t5DFL9AjCtEaouJjK%2BcDs%2B8Cs%2FvByghUsoPASvaBdePxk%2BNhVehch%2FVYEPiCBIywMcsPgKrPAIZzuKRwTknsGgUJ%2FQiqFpDoxtjstplFmthOGqHT8e%2FtTmNkR6OxgoDVuQZJPeROtxG2jPHcAahanThRnxUdb3Vux3b3BjnGVWR2AeCdm%2B8A1R2%2BXfyYXUcB0lwAzfwJNOIGUcBVrHON6QgopA5Vln0oyJ9YQR6XJ3C12vKPPY8PxL4dYl8lKgGSsLSS4%2B0mIoAGI7S8QY8Zpk%2F3EzVMDng%2BT1fPkyB%2B%2FJc2wAd1KzyfppM8zSAFY68XxErkfw6y%2FKD3OfQqIUKQNzB6%2FThhmqkHqsrHC4P5NM3UNRkOD4SGXqVUbD1fduh2g0YkxuWDQAA89VbSqzbGvx1lxgEZ2ptAI1x7nrqjcDiK4bd4DhpHoT56lYNZVPsJWPoG9UFV9QCqDiuE2uAB1v7B4f8OHH4f59GrwBw0chDnYXs5j65qKxXiyKRHI5rOOdQqwojmbk3zHcHa%2F8p6LHXMuMGtzpibUXthTR6D9Ta0uzazI8VynLGdXIV2p4nUPgiwHdS6tACw1xGwHYBQY%2BR04XPHiR3DX9qJAqpJHWNIACwwd3PRMtrcSerfBKsDx31ykzcnt9jrtsHXq5G1PA%2FNxFZAXDqJuu%2FcgLma1Insewf%2B2pHPLaPGzNX9adZS96ujIbbAt1Zpsx0O7tCbsR5ZRYKgIy5t6gU5QAyQHqxID%2FtON1FlVTABMx%2BSXPzHJBfGnHDJOOLsfSTXPVTmBQAQaH8NP1kJLq9CVelNVdWXQ%2BokbSUxVHIxc9kGMI8XZqKSq87MLlT6y%2Fa93W1je3kFssOcW0lz6VzeLCDhIAmdEFYPkBW175ZcICXU5iMcv4EVq%2F3GyaVrkqMjSgoGDeQ6u7g4ZnI9T8HK%2F0%2BASibJz7BybXMwiBaVYLxAAutU%2F1jYfuaF7Rksqzdn1OszvsqDMqFyN1N3wrOnObnGsvjWywvr3usnnv97egIq8kvOrv7vBjf4vMqVPPgdoPbn%2FwGSB1Nz'; zlib.decompress(base64.decodestring(urllib.unquote(m)))"
```

Final result is:

```
{"app_id":"124024574287414","uid":"0","time":1483722700.043034,"app_ver":"10.3.0 (46070771)","device_id":"1B758FB6-DC9F-4FD1-8C8D-6A848DADA0C7","family_device_id":"43C4D2EE-8FDE-428D-91CA-D5A724A1549A","session_id":"BA0E0CF1-42F8-432C-BB62-2F5B48369B63","data":[{"module":"app","name":"websocket_connect_attempt","time":1483722692.504779,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164"}},{"module":"app","name":"ig_qe_exposure","time":1483722692.58945,"extra":{"group":"test_social_context_on_client","id":"2284338164","pk":"2284338164","experiment":"ig_ios_feed_ufi_redesign"}},{"module":"app","name":"ig_qe_exposure","time":1483722692.589543,"extra":{"group":"test","id":"2284338164","pk":"2284338164","experiment":"ig_ios_save"}},{"module":"app","name":"ig_qe_exposure","time":1483722692.593709,"extra":{"group":"rollout","id":"2284338164","pk":"2284338164","experiment":"ig_ios_save_feed_tooltip"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"reel_tray_impression","time":1483722692.812107,"extra":{"tray_position":0,"pk":"2284338164","live_reel_count":0,"tray_session_id":"4ba09935da694e4e970ee8b11c9faac2","muted_reel_count":0,"a_pk":"2284338164","has_my_reel":0,"viewed_reel_count":0,"new_reel_count":0,"is_new_reel":1}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"reel_tray_impression","time":1483722692.817618,"extra":{"tray_position":0,"pk":"2284338164","live_reel_count":0,"tray_session_id":"4ba09935da694e4e970ee8b11c9faac2","muted_reel_count":0,"a_pk":"25025320","has_my_reel":0,"viewed_reel_count":0,"new_reel_count":0,"is_new_reel":1}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"reel_tray_impression","time":1483722692.822306,"extra":{"tray_position":0,"pk":"2284338164","live_reel_count":0,"tray_session_id":"4ba09935da694e4e970ee8b11c9faac2","muted_reel_count":0,"a_pk":"196198987","has_my_reel":0,"viewed_reel_count":0,"new_reel_count":0,"is_new_reel":1}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"reel_tray_impression","time":1483722692.826773,"extra":{"tray_position":0,"pk":"2284338164","live_reel_count":0,"tray_session_id":"4ba09935da694e4e970ee8b11c9faac2","muted_reel_count":0,"a_pk":"575697306","has_my_reel":0,"viewed_reel_count":0,"new_reel_count":0,"is_new_reel":1}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"reel_tray_impression","time":1483722692.831488,"extra":{"tray_position":0,"pk":"2284338164","live_reel_count":0,"tray_session_id":"4ba09935da694e4e970ee8b11c9faac2","muted_reel_count":0,"a_pk":"290691036","has_my_reel":0,"viewed_reel_count":0,"new_reel_count":0,"is_new_reel":1}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_sub_impression","time":1483722692.84102,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":0,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"1487230826","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","m_pk":"1421627016431640101_1487230826","tracking_token":"eyJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJzZXJ2ZXJfdG9rZW4iOiIxNDgzNzE0NDYyNDI2fDE0MjE2MjcwMTY0MzE2NDAxMDF8MjI4NDMzODE2NHw2YjAwZDY2NGY1NDNjZGNiOTJkOGQwYzUxMzVhYzhhOWIyZjY0YjlmYmIxNjFiNTA2NjYwODFkOWIxMDNkYmY4IiwidXVpZCI6Ijc5ZjQ2NTAyYWZkOTQ2NWVhYmVjZmQzNWM1NzU0YjI2MTQyMTYyNzAxNjQzMTY0MDEwMSJ9LCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"app","name":"ig_qe_exposure","time":1483722692.841793,"extra":{"group":"TEST","id":"2284338164","pk":"2284338164","experiment":"ig_ios_feed_video_cell_autoplay_bugfix"}},{"module":"device","name":"connection_change","time":1483722692.899129,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164","connection":"wifi","connection_subtype":"CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA"}},{"module":"application","name":"launch_usable","time":1483722692.932535,"extra":{"device":"iPhone8,1","os":"10.1.1","init_to_launch_ms":159.7147916691029,"pk":"2284338164","init_to_now_ms":1051.190583333664,"background_init":false,"init_to_active_ms":617.7668750024168,"init_to_usable_ms":891.4757916645613}},{"module":"application","name":"push_notification_setting","time":1483722692.940062,"extra":{"badges":true,"alerts":true,"sounds":true,"pk":"2284338164","app_state":"launch_usable","badge_number":0,"last_badge_number":0,"raw_setting":7}},{"module":"app","name":"direct_ui_perf","time":1483722692.971275,"extra":{"first_page":true,"result":"success","pk":"2284338164","view":"inbox","type":"request_time","total_duration":695}},{"module":"app","name":"realtime_subscribe_attempt","time":1483722692.976333,"extra":{"realtime_topic":"user-ds2-2284338164~2","pk":"2284338164","realtime_subscription_already_exists":false}},{"module":"app","name":"content_loaded","time":1483722692.984203,"extra":{"content_type":"photo","pk":"2284338164","content_load_time":0.1976552499982063,"content_width":750}},{"module":"app","name":"websocket_did_open","time":1483722693.956506,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164"}},{"module":"app","name":"realtime_subscribed","time":1483722694.343897,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164","realtime_topic":"user-ds2-2284338164~2"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"reel_tray_refresh","time":1483722694.437768,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164","live_reel_count":0,"tray_session_id":"4ba09935da694e4e970ee8b11c9faac2","was_successful":true,"muted_reel_count":0,"tray_refresh_type":"network","viewed_reel_count":0,"new_reel_count":9,"tray_refresh_time":0.4671275000000605,"has_my_reel":1}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"reel_tray_impression","time":1483722694.451732,"extra":{"tray_position":3,"pk":"2284338164","live_reel_count":0,"tray_session_id":"4ba09935da694e4e970ee8b11c9faac2","muted_reel_count":0,"a_pk":"1573917928","has_my_reel":1,"viewed_reel_count":0,"new_reel_count":9,"is_new_reel":1}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_main_feed_refresh","time":1483722694.63361,"extra":{"reason":"cold_start_fetch","pk":"2284338164","status_code":"200"}},{"module":"app","name":"app_installations","time":1483722694.8347,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164","fbapp_installed":true}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_impression","time":1483722695.036799,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":0,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"2263699430","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","m_pk":"1421834952577120803_2263699430","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5NzZ8MTQyMTgzNDk1MjU3NzEyMDgwM3wyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDEyNTgxMjQ3ODdmYWMzODA5N2RkM2M4MjhlNWUxNGFjMjcyOTUzNGRiMDVhNzk5NTViOTc0NWFjNGEwNTUxMGMiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXVpZCI6ImE3MGIyZjIxNzNmZjQzMWNhMjdmNjFlMjdiNzk0MDgwMTQyMTgzNDk1MjU3NzEyMDgwMyJ9fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_time_spent","time":1483722695.036946,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"1487230826","timespent":2.195435047149658,"m_pk":"1421627016431640101_1487230826","tracking_token":"eyJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJzZXJ2ZXJfdG9rZW4iOiIxNDgzNzE0NDYyNDI2fDE0MjE2MjcwMTY0MzE2NDAxMDF8MjI4NDMzODE2NHw2YjAwZDY2NGY1NDNjZGNiOTJkOGQwYzUxMzVhYzhhOWIyZjY0YjlmYmIxNjFiNTA2NjYwODFkOWIxMDNkYmY4IiwidXVpZCI6Ijc5ZjQ2NTAyYWZkOTQ2NWVhYmVjZmQzNWM1NzU0YjI2MTQyMTYyNzAxNjQzMTY0MDEwMSJ9LCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_sub_viewed_impression","time":1483722695.036983,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","follow_status":"following","m_t":1,"a_pk":"1487230826","m_pk":"1421627016431640101_1487230826","pk":"2284338164","tracking_token":"eyJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJzZXJ2ZXJfdG9rZW4iOiIxNDgzNzE0NDYyNDI2fDE0MjE2MjcwMTY0MzE2NDAxMDF8MjI4NDMzODE2NHw2YjAwZDY2NGY1NDNjZGNiOTJkOGQwYzUxMzVhYzhhOWIyZjY0YjlmYmIxNjFiNTA2NjYwODFkOWIxMDNkYmY4IiwidXVpZCI6Ijc5ZjQ2NTAyYWZkOTQ2NWVhYmVjZmQzNWM1NzU0YjI2MTQyMTYyNzAxNjQzMTY0MDEwMSJ9LCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1fQ=="}},{"module":"app","name":"content_loaded","time":1483722695.558961,"extra":{"content_type":"photo","pk":"2284338164","content_load_time":0.8762567916637636,"content_width":750}},{"module":"app","name":"content_loaded","time":1483722695.576639,"extra":{"content_type":"photo","pk":"2284338164","content_load_time":0.400949374998163,"content_width":750}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_impression","time":1483722696.305709,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":1,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"204327608","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","m_pk":"1421889687605301135_204327608","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5NzZ8MTQyMTg4OTY4NzYwNTMwMTEzNXwyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDY5ZTgwODY2NzkwMWU1YTdiMGEwM2NkYTRlNmQyYzNjNjNkY2M3NTZjMDIwNzE1OGQ2YTc0NTE1NDZhZjQ2OGIiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXVpZCI6ImE3MGIyZjIxNzNmZjQzMWNhMjdmNjFlMjdiNzk0MDgwMTQyMTg4OTY4NzYwNTMwMTEzNSJ9fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"hscroll_aymf_feed_unit","name":"recommended_user_impression","time":1483722696.32221,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164","uid":"2316545717","view":"hscroll_aymf_feed_unit","position":0,"algorithm":"followers_algorithm"}},{"module":"hscroll_aymf_feed_unit","name":"recommended_user_impression","time":1483722696.326252,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164","uid":"3896352675","view":"hscroll_aymf_feed_unit","position":1,"algorithm":"followers_algorithm"}},{"module":"hscroll_aymf_feed_unit","name":"recommended_user_impression","time":1483722696.329706,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164","uid":"2942400495","view":"hscroll_aymf_feed_unit","position":2,"algorithm":"page_rank_algorithm"}},{"module":"app","name":"content_loaded","time":1483722696.490827,"extra":{"content_type":"photo","pk":"2284338164","content_load_time":0.0478957499981334,"content_width":799}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_time_spent","time":1483722697.295841,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":0,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"2263699430","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","timespent":2.258677005767822,"m_pk":"1421834952577120803_2263699430","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5NzZ8MTQyMTgzNDk1MjU3NzEyMDgwM3wyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDEyNTgxMjQ3ODdmYWMzODA5N2RkM2M4MjhlNWUxNGFjMjcyOTUzNGRiMDVhNzk5NTViOTc0NWFjNGEwNTUxMGMiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXVpZCI6ImE3MGIyZjIxNzNmZjQzMWNhMjdmNjFlMjdiNzk0MDgwMTQyMTgzNDk1MjU3NzEyMDgwMyJ9fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_viewed_impression","time":1483722697.296037,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":0,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"2263699430","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","m_pk":"1421834952577120803_2263699430","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5NzZ8MTQyMTgzNDk1MjU3NzEyMDgwM3wyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDEyNTgxMjQ3ODdmYWMzODA5N2RkM2M4MjhlNWUxNGFjMjcyOTUzNGRiMDVhNzk5NTViOTc0NWFjNGEwNTUxMGMiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXVpZCI6ImE3MGIyZjIxNzNmZjQzMWNhMjdmNjFlMjdiNzk0MDgwMTQyMTgzNDk1MjU3NzEyMDgwMyJ9fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_impression","time":1483722697.422587,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":2,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"290691036","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","m_pk":"1421785804972142074_290691036","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5NzZ8MTQyMTc4NTgwNDk3MjE0MjA3NHwyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDNjMDFkMWQ4N2I1YmFiZTcxYTFhYjhkMDgwNTRhYzg5ZWFiODkwZGRiNTlmODkwNjNjOTVkYWU0ZDJjMWM2MTUiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXVpZCI6ImE3MGIyZjIxNzNmZjQzMWNhMjdmNjFlMjdiNzk0MDgwMTQyMTc4NTgwNDk3MjE0MjA3NCJ9fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_time_spent","time":1483722697.557526,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":1,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"204327608","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","timespent":1.185648024082184,"m_pk":"1421889687605301135_204327608","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5NzZ8MTQyMTg4OTY4NzYwNTMwMTEzNXwyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDY5ZTgwODY2NzkwMWU1YTdiMGEwM2NkYTRlNmQyYzNjNjNkY2M3NTZjMDIwNzE1OGQ2YTc0NTE1NDZhZjQ2OGIiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXVpZCI6ImE3MGIyZjIxNzNmZjQzMWNhMjdmNjFlMjdiNzk0MDgwMTQyMTg4OTY4NzYwNTMwMTEzNSJ9fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_viewed_impression","time":1483722697.557715,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":1,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"204327608","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","m_pk":"1421889687605301135_204327608","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5NzZ8MTQyMTg4OTY4NzYwNTMwMTEzNXwyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDY5ZTgwODY2NzkwMWU1YTdiMGEwM2NkYTRlNmQyYzNjNjNkY2M3NTZjMDIwNzE1OGQ2YTc0NTE1NDZhZjQ2OGIiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXVpZCI6ImE3MGIyZjIxNzNmZjQzMWNhMjdmNjFlMjdiNzk0MDgwMTQyMTg4OTY4NzYwNTMwMTEzNSJ9fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"app","name":"content_loaded","time":1483722697.578529,"extra":{"content_type":"photo","pk":"2284338164","content_load_time":0.02764237500014133,"content_width":612}},{"module":"app","name":"ig_qe_exposure","time":1483722698.19705,"extra":{"group":"test","id":"2284338164","pk":"2284338164","experiment":"ig_ios_ad_new_sponsored_label_universe"}},{"module":"app","name":"ig_qe_exposure","time":1483722698.227725,"extra":{"group":"test","id":"2284338164","pk":"2284338164","experiment":"ig_ios_video_corrected_viewport_logging"}},{"module":"app","name":"content_loaded","time":1483722698.33762,"extra":{"content_type":"photo","pk":"2284338164","content_load_time":0.04629112499969779,"content_width":750}},{"module":"app","name":"ig_qe_exposure","time":1483722698.457056,"extra":{"group":"test","id":"2284338164","pk":"2284338164","experiment":"ig_ios_ad_intent_to_highlight_universe"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_time_spent","time":1483722698.522836,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":2,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"290691036","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","timespent":0.991282045841217,"m_pk":"1421785804972142074_290691036","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5NzZ8MTQyMTc4NTgwNDk3MjE0MjA3NHwyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDNjMDFkMWQ4N2I1YmFiZTcxYTFhYjhkMDgwNTRhYzg5ZWFiODkwZGRiNTlmODkwNjNjOTVkYWU0ZDJjMWM2MTUiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXVpZCI6ImE3MGIyZjIxNzNmZjQzMWNhMjdmNjFlMjdiNzk0MDgwMTQyMTc4NTgwNDk3MjE0MjA3NCJ9fQ==","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_impression","time":1483722698.605625,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":4,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"2082772377","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","m_pk":"1421886268559992426_2082772377","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5Nzd8MTQyMTg4NjI2ODU1OTk5MjQyNnwyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDViYWY4YjEwM2ZkYmJiYTI0MjcyNmQ0OGNkMDRjY2MzNmFhZWRjYTZlZDczYmNjOTM3ZDg2MjA2OTIyODQ5ZmEiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6ZmFsc2UsInV1aWQiOiJhNzBiMmYyMTczZmY0MzFjYTI3ZjYxZTI3Yjc5NDA4MDE0MjE4ODYyNjg1NTk5OTI0MjYifX0=","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"app","name":"content_loaded","time":1483722699.07202,"extra":{"content_type":"photo","pk":"2284338164","content_load_time":0.02502862500114134,"content_width":750}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_impression","time":1483722699.747028,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":5,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"2082772377","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","m_pk":"1421886211525945054_2082772377","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5Nzd8MTQyMTg4NjIxMTUyNTk0NTA1NHwyMjg0MzM4MTY0fGJiNTRhMDkwNzg3ZmQ5ZTg0Mjc4MzQ5NDkyMmRjY2E4MWJjMGQxYWQ1YzJiMGMwNmIzZGUyYTZkMDZiYjhhZjAiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6ZmFsc2UsInV1aWQiOiJhNzBiMmYyMTczZmY0MzFjYTI3ZjYxZTI3Yjc5NDA4MDE0MjE4ODYyMTE1MjU5NDUwNTQifX0=","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"app","name":"content_loaded","time":1483722699.869509,"extra":{"content_type":"photo","pk":"2284338164","content_load_time":0.0443396250011574,"content_width":750}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"instagram_organic_time_spent","time":1483722700.039492,"extra":{"source_of_action":"feed_timeline","m_t":1,"m_ix":4,"pk":"2284338164","a_pk":"2082772377","session_id":"2284338164_22006D1E-0336-4815-9429-A49B7EC70FD6","timespent":0.9339390397071838,"m_pk":"1421886268559992426_2082772377","tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7InNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE0ODM3MjI2OTM5Nzd8MTQyMTg4NjI2ODU1OTk5MjQyNnwyMjg0MzM4MTY0fDViYWY4YjEwM2ZkYmJiYTI0MjcyNmQ0OGNkMDRjY2MzNmFhZWRjYTZlZDczYmNjOTM3ZDg2MjA2OTIyODQ5ZmEiLCJpc19hbmFseXRpY3NfdHJhY2tlZCI6ZmFsc2UsInV1aWQiOiJhNzBiMmYyMTczZmY0MzFjYTI3ZjYxZTI3Yjc5NDA4MDE0MjE4ODYyNjg1NTk5OTI0MjYifX0=","follow_status":"following"}},{"module":"feed_timeline","name":"perf_percent_photos_rendered","time":1483722700.03977,"extra":{"pk":"2284338164","rendered":true}}],"log_type":"client_event","seq":0}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day :)

Comment: Or if this is just for debugging purposes, write it to a file and gunzip -c on the command line.

Comment: @nirizr Do you know how to generate that tracking token?

Comment: Sorry, no. At least, not without getting some more information about the application involved.

Comment: "tracking_token": "eyJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJzZXJ2ZXJfdG9rZW4iOiIxNDgzNzE0NDYyNDI2fDE0MjE2MjcwMTY0MzE2NDAxMDF8MjI4NDMzODE2NHw2YjAwZDY2NGY1NDNjZGNiOTJkOGQwYzUxMzVhYzhhOWIyZjY0YjlmYmIxNjFiNTA2NjYwODFkOWIxMDNkYmY4IiwidXVpZCI6Ijc5ZjQ2NTAyYWZkOTQ2NWVhYmVjZmQzNWM1NzU0YjI2MTQyMTYyNzAxNjQzMTY0MDEwMSJ9LCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1fQ==" this is tracking token in this project its base64 encoded. When I decode i find one hash value. Do you(@NirIzr) know what is that ?

Comment: {"signature":"","payload":{"is_analytics_tracked":true,"server_token":"1483714462426|1421627016431640101|2284338164|6b00d664f543cdcb92d8d0c5135ac8a9b2f64b9fbb161b50666081d9b103dbf8","uuid":"79f46502afd9465eabecfd35c5754b261421627016431640101"},"version":5} this is converted value. I need to know what is this value "6b00d664f543cdcb92d8d0c5135ac8a9b2f64b9fbb161b50666081d9b103dbf8". Do you (@NirIzr, @deepak-sharma)guys know about it?

Comment: Do you have a latest version response ? @DeepakSharma

Comment: Not anymore, everything is changed now. I have moved on from that project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gzuncompress` in php :

https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.gzuncompress.php

```
<?php
$compressed   = gzcompress('Compresse moi', 9); // or $compressed   = "YOUrcOmpreSSedStRINg";
$uncompressed = gzuncompress($compressed);
echo $uncompressed;
?>
```

Comment: The OP is developing on ios (that the iphone's operating system). A PHP solution isn't appropriate.

Comment: I just tried but it gives an error with data. What could be wrong?

Comment: I edited the question with full post request headers + data.

Comment: I think the message body may not be gzip compressed data, any idea we can get whether it is compressed, or compressed+encrypted?

Comment: If it is just compressed, gunzip -c filename will extract the data.  If it is encrypted, good luck.

Comment: Can you help me @DeepakSharma to know how to make tracking_token in runtime?

Comment: It is simple, just look for "organic_tracking_token" field in the json you receive in list of recent media posted by user.

Comment: I tried but view count not increased. Have you a working file for view? @DeepakSharma

Comment: View count increasing is not that trivial, it depends on the version of Instagram. You just asked how to extract token.

Comment: I asked to know about view count because the data you provided it return from view call. Do you have working file for that? @DeepakSharma

Comment: Can you please help me out here ? @DeepakSharma