# How can I reverse engineer the encode method used here?

Tags: hash, encoding, base64, reverse-engineering, decoding

I have a string:

`RP581147238IN` which gets encoded as `A3294Fc0Mb0V1Tb4aBK8rw==`

and another string:

`RP581147239IN` which gets encoded as `A3294Fc0Mb1BPqxRDrRXjQ==`

But after spending a day, I still cannot figure out what is the encoding process.

The encoded string looks like its base64 encoded.

But when I decode it, it looks like:
base64.decodestring("A3294Fc0Mb0V1Tb4aBK8rw==")
`\x03}\xbd\xe0W41\xbdA>\xacQ\x0e\xb4W\x8d`

The base 64 decoded string now is looking like a zlib compressed string

I've tried to further use zlib decompression methods but none of them worked.

```
import zlib, base64
rt = 'A3294Fc0Mb1BPqxRDrRXjQ=='

for i in range(-50, 50):
    try:                                      
        print(zlib.decompress(base64.decodestring(rt), i));
        print("{} worked".format(i))
        break
    except:
        pass
```

But that did not produce any results either.

Can anybody figure out what is the encoding process used here. @Nirlzr, I am looking at you for the heroic answer you provided in [Reverse Engineer HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509066/reverse-engineer-http-request).

Comment: @Nirlzr, I am looking at you for the help

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can help here. Unless you're willing to do a lot more work, you'll need to reverse engineer the code generating those outputs to figure out what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The strings seem to be Base64 encoded and the underlying decoded data seems to be encrypted. Encrypted data can not be directly represented as a string and it is common the Base64 encode encrypted data when a string is required.

If this is the case you need to decrypt the decoded data and ignorer to accomplish that you would need the encryption key.

Note: In general it is not productive to compress such short items.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your data strings side by side:

```
RP581147238IN A3294Fc0Mb0V1Tb4aBK8rw==
RP581147239IN A3294Fc0Mb1BPqxRDrRXjQ==
```

You can see that source strings have only character difference, but encoded version contains 12 different characters:

```
  ----------8-- ----------0V1Tb4aBK8rw--
  ----------9-- ----------1BPqxRDrRXjQ--
```

Encoded data has similar paddings at the end as base64, but definitely it is not base64. Probably crypted with some SHA-like algorithm. With the data you provided, I would say that it is not possible to reverse-engineer the encoding process. Probably more data would not help much either.