# Reverse Engineering HTTP request

Tags: android, instagram, reverse-engineering

I am trying to decode the post data sent to graph.instagram.com by the Android instagram app. The question is simillar to the one found here:

[Reverse Engineer HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509066/reverse-engineer-http-request)

It seems that either the iPhone app handles this differently to the Android app or something has changed since that question was asked. I've captured the traffic using Burp and it seems the main data is now sent to IG as a .gz file:

```
POST /logging_client_events HTTP/1.1
X-IG-Connection-Type: WIFI
X-IG-Capabilities: 3brTAw==
X-IG-App-ID: 567067343352427
User-Agent: Instagram 24.0.0.11.201 Android (23/6.0; 240dpi; 480x854; LENOVO/Lenovo; Lenovo A2016a40; A2016a40; mt6735; en_GB)
Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=EuG_-5FMs7IwTX7eBzBDIJ9VEteYsO
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: graph.instagram.com
X-FB-HTTP-Engine: Liger
Connection: close
Content-Length: 4206

--EuG_-5FMs7IwTX7eBzBDIJ9VEteYsO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="access_token"

567067343352427|f249176f09e26ce54212b472dbab8fa8
--EuG_-5FMs7IwTX7eBzBDIJ9VEteYsO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="format"

json
--EuG_-5FMs7IwTX7eBzBDIJ9VEteYsO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cmsg"; filename="a24cc6f3-23f1-438f-aecb-3f201d312c90_1.batch.gz"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

í][sÚHý/<ÇÞ¾ª»]µÎÈÎâZ‰M›H[[*!HHÀ"0—©ùïûµ„mƒ2v‚�ÎTRCß/ç|§ïú½VÄÿ«�áµp<’Ní¬Æ-�,A¥œ0"j•×m<?ÂNü‡ñ)A|Ú³$ëÃY~IŽ  ¶À¹ß&Q\%GÛ(–�=a´‹NÕ‰dqû$Æ²’�Ðn‡B”n˜'Ù2øŽ˜E\ÉhXÅ       ‹"«KOÀCDÙ= ã¨}B»PàÅ$RâÌÊÀúÿ¢Ñ°›ô‚¨Gƒ¢¬G[p£H°PÑ¸2L¥$¡âmÊCÅ"ò  ÚDçqnK×~8ÆüœÄ½YNtK„Ó°vöŸßkÃ0�Á'Ó°7    ó`4é…Ã$
n“xw‚$OªŠ@¬iRÆÐžÄ„óSiqpÏG�Y¦}º1DÑ¡²dƒG¼˜N Ÿßky0è˜–…±Dq‚1—J   p�âŒa]í°
÷È-¦@AgÊ¢¢t©�(Ï$ŒÉ°LGƒX×7^^ÿëÕ*l©Y=áþv5÷¾fE›\êéXÔólõ•\Î¼Ö‚w>ei„ŠòË4$7Ú?÷•ÿïyÒùz3ö«[õô*÷Ó‹¥×tæ�OW©Ÿ~IœfÄ\;Kò7šYæÚ7™ÛúÌ�¦Gœæsì‹¹Û¬/œæ5k4Ôýw½¨Ý,úY”)Ô&Ó¬�è´/°Ó¬/Ý4ZºÍÏ�æ¥Ü™Æ×9qÓkÔ°ÏWŽ}Í»ö€9«Næ§uÒ«ÔI=ä¥ýÄùt½tí/    ¤Gv6ðs¿ïÚ×Ôµ¯ò†}™5Z/ÿOnâØ=î~ºÊtÞN³ŸøÍÏIê‘lØÎ/QçëUm˜Ô‡èïÎ£Ù0êa4­ÐõmowGY6š€¤é¬ÐþåoèŸ²“Eí}

--EuG_-5FMs7IwTX7eBzBDIJ9VEteYsO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sent_time"

1512267283.408
--EuG_-5FMs7IwTX7eBzBDIJ9VEteYsO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cmethod"

deflate
--EuG_-5FMs7IwTX7eBzBDIJ9VEteYsO--
```

For some reason I am unable to paste the 'gibberish' below binary fully and it cuts off after a few lines.

Any idea how this is encoded? it's supposed to be .gz but the output from Burp doesn't look anything like it. Is there anyway I can save the file so I can inspect it? Burp, nor fiddler seem to support anything like that.

Comment: You can easily save the file by using fiddler!!

Comment: I'm a fiddler user and don't know how to save the bytes into file in burp.. But if your concern is to only get the file regardless from which software you get it, I can help you!!

Comment: `Any idea how this is encoded? `. Well .gz as you already stated. `filename="a24cc6f3-23f1-438f-aecb-3f201d312c90_1.batch.gz"`. And `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`.

Comment: `unable to paste the 'gibberish' below binary fully `. Unclear how you copy/paste. And isnt that for text?

Comment: @ArsalImam How would I go about retrieving that file using fiddler. I spent a few hours fiddling but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @greenapps Yes, I suppose when binary file is represented as text like burp does it's bound to look like gibberish. My question then is how can I use Burp or other such proxy software to retrieve the .gz file for me?

Comment: Firstly, it is a binary file that's why you're getting the content!! you can move the hex tab in fiddler and export the binary to a file and download it!!

Comment: Are you guys able to decode this binary data to text format ? @user2108369

Comment: @ArsalImam hi,Do you know how to decode this binary data to text format ? Have you ever done this ?

Comment: yes, you can convert it into String(base64) which convert the binary into text format

Answer (score 2):

To decompress it use inflater that omit header check

```
Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS).inflate(File.read("*.batch.gz"))
```

In the ruby doc we might read this

```
Zlib::Inflate.new(window_bits = Zlib::MAX_WBITS)
```

Creates a new inflate stream for decompression. window_bits sets the size of the history buffer and can have the following values:

- 0 - Have inflate use the window size from the zlib header of the
  compressed stream.
- (8..15) -
  Overrides the window size of the inflate header in the compressed stream. The window size must be greater than or equal to the window size of the compressed stream.
- Greater than 15 Add 32 - to window_bits to enable zlib and gzip
  decoding with automatic header detection, or add 16 to decode only
  the gzip format (a Zlib::DataError will be raised for a non-gzip
  stream).
- (-8..-15) - Enables raw deflate mode which will not generate a check
  value, and will not look for any check values for comparison at the
  end of the stream.

This is for use with other formats that use the deflate compressed data format such as zip which provide their own check values.

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/Inflate.html